# Wired mouse not connecting on boot

Tags: mouse, 18.10

I have a corsair m65 pro, I never unplug it, but when I boot into Ubuntu 18.10, from a shutdown the mouse isn't recognized until after I unplug it in, and reinsert it. Only then does the mouse work. The lights do not turn on, it appears that it does not even turn on when the computer is turned on. I did completely reinstall Ubuntu and the issue is still present.

Comment: is it a USB or PS/2 mouse? If it's USB are there any other USB devices suffering?

Comment: It is a USB mouse, no other USB devices are suffering